# Trying to print out the values of an Associative Array - Error: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to echo the values of an associative array that contains all the rows in a table using `foreach` in a table.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
    $result = doSql("SELECT * FROM carts WHERE userID =".$userID);
     if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        $cartRows = mysqli_fetch_all($result); 

             foreach($cartRows as $key => $value) {

                echo "<tr>
                    <td scope='col'>" .$value['cartID']. "</td>
                    <td scope='col'>" .$value["productToCartQty"]. "</td>
                    <td scope='col' colspan='2'>".$value['invoiced']."</td>
                    <td scope='col' colspan='2'>" .$value['customization']."</td>
                   </tr>";
                }
            } 
 ?>
```

> The error: Array to string conversion

I don't understand why I'm getting this error as I am only echoing out the value inside of the array `$value` i.e. echo $value['cartID']?

**Here is the screenshot of the error:**
https://gyazo.com/cdc8dde8c2e09e91b5209c2b50bcb72c

Any ideas?

Comment: Do `print_r($cartRows)` before `foreach` and see if its really an array

Comment: you can use mysqli_fetch_array($result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
$cartRows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

to:

```
$cartRows = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Omg! It worked. The reason why I left out the second parameter is because it was optional (I researched). Can please explain why I was getting the error: String to Array conversion if I don't have that parameter?